# Insert Data to tblEducation using asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have 2 tables in database:tbleducation,tblemployee.Anyway for table tblemployee, I have fields: employeeID,employeeName....I want to insert data into tbleducation that have fields such as:EmployeeID,Duration,.....And for the EmployeeID of table tbleducation I want to do the dropdownlist that list all EmployeeName in tblEmployee into dropdownlist.And I have code as below:

**View**

```
<div id="Education">
<%Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Education","EmployeeProfile")){%>
 <% Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Unsuccessfull"); %>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Employee Name</td>
          <td><%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EmployeeName, Model.Employee, "select EmployeeName")%</td>
          <td>Duration</td>
          <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Duration, new { id="duration",name="duration"})%>
      <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Duration) %></td>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Add" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   <%}%>
</div>
```

**Model**

```
public class UserModels
{

    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Employee { set; get; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Education() {

        var query = (from e in context.tblEmployee_Employee
                     select new
                     {
                         empID = e.Code,
                         EmpName = e.NameEng
                     }
                              ).ToList();

        var model = new UserModels();
        var _Emp = query;
        foreach (var item in _Emp)
        {
            model.EmployeeCode = item.empID;
            model.EmployeeName = item.EmpName;
            model.Employee = new SelectList(_Emp, "EmpName", "EmpName");

        }
        return View(model);
    }
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Education(UserModels model, FormCollection edu) {
        tblEmployee_Education education = new tblEmployee_Education();

        education.Duration = edu["Duration"].ToString();
        education.Certificate = edu["Certificate"].ToString();
        education.Country = edu["Country"].ToString();
        education.SchoolName = edu["SchoolName"].ToString();
        education.Major = edu["Major"].ToString();
        education.SubDescript = edu["SubDescript"].ToString();
        string EName = edu["EmployeeName"].ToString();
        return Content(
           string.Format(
               "Selected role for {0} is {1}", model.EmployeeName, model.EmployeeCode
           )
       );
        context.AddTotblEmployee_Education(education);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return View("Personal");
    }
```

I got the warning message "unreachble code detected".I really do not know how to solve it.Please kindly help me,

Thanks in advanced,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your POST action, here:

```
return Content(
    string.Format(
        "Selected role for {0} is {1}", model.EmployeeName, model.EmployeeCode
    )
);
```

you have already returned a result and the action execution ends.

So get rid of the lines that follow it, they will never be executed:

```
context.AddTotblEmployee_Education(education);
context.SaveChanges();
return View("Personal");
```

And if you want them to be executed, then remove the `return Content(...)` line.

Comment: Thanks you so much,I ready remove but it has the error "object reference not set an instance of and object".And error with this line:<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EmployeeName, Model.Employee, "select EmployeeName")%> in view page.Help me please, Thanks